# Run several likely-to-crash R scripts

Tags: r

I have several scripts that are likely to crash. Is there a way to run these R scripts (perhaps from a different R script), in a way such that if one if them crashes, it doesn't pull down the others?

These are independent R scripts, running on Windows. By crashing I mean that when I try to run them in the R Gui, after some while Windows tells me R GUI stopped responding: Close program / Find solution.

Comment: There's crashing and there's crashing. What sort of crash is it? Also, what operating system is running these scripts? And why would one script crashing pull down the others? How are they dependent? Or are they running in sequence? You don't say.

Answer (score 4):

Catch errors using `tryCatch()`, and stop execution using `stop()`.

You can do these within a single script by wrapping them within a function, or you can `source()` scripts within scripts. This decision should really be dictated by your problem's logical structure and your programming practice, not by how errors are caught.